# Problems in Playwright when running a test within Microsoft login

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test

**Details:**

Currently I have a problem with Playwright. A test build of a website has a normal login with username and password. This login also works in the test, but after the login another query by Microsoft Login follows. The recorder of Playwright also records this login, but then does not resolve it when the test is executed.

**Steps to reproduce:**
1.) Login with Email (Mainpage)
2nd) After login appears query by Microsoft login (Will be recorded by Playwrigt recorder as well).
3) During the execution only the first login is noticed, but the Microsoft login is not executed (password is not entered).

**Tooling:**

- Playwright (Full Installation/ Functional)
- Python 3.10

**Code:**

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()

# Open new page
page = context.new_page()

# Go to https://xxx.dev/
page.goto("https://xxx.dev/")

# Click [placeholder="Bitte gib deine Email Adresse ein"]
page.locator("[placeholder=\"Bitte gib deine Email Adresse ein\"]").click()

# Fill [placeholder="Bitte gib deine Email Adresse ein"]
page.locator("[placeholder=\"Bitte gib deine Email Adresse ein\"]").fill("youremai@.com")

# Click button:has-text("Einloggen")
page.locator("button:has-text(\"Einloggen\")").click()
page.wait_for_url("https://login.live.com/oauth20_xxx")

# Click #lightbox
page.locator("#lightbox").click()

# Click [placeholder="Kennwort"]
page.locator("[placeholder=\"Kennwort\"]").click()

# Fill [placeholder="Kennwort"]
page.locator("[placeholder=\"Kennwort\"]").fill("xxx")

# Click text=Anmelden
page.locator("text=Anmelden").click()
page.wait_for_url("https://xxx.dev")

# Click text=Nein
page.locator("text=Nein").click()
page.wait_for_url("https://xxx.dev/")

# Click text=×For the best user experience and a quick tour through the app, please use your  >> button
page.locator("text=×For the best user experience and a quick tour through the app, please use your  >> button").click()

# ---------------------
context.close()
browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
run(playwright)
```

Comment: Hey @Thorsten, I have not used codegen as such but this kind of issue has happened to me when the locator is inside **iframe**, And since it is external Microsoft login it seems to be a third-party iframe. Please check if it helps